# combine SimpleXMLElement Object [content] elements into a variable

Tags: php, curl, rss, simplexml

Hello I have the following php code, from the output $doc I want to take all the [content] items and put them together for use in a tag cloud. How can I extract all the [content] items into one variable?

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.sysomos.com/hb/v1/heartbeat/rss?startid=0&hbrss=DUpnCTqppKjx4q1U6FXd5SWOPFUa2ltLm1haXJAYi1hbmQtcS5jby51aw..&maxC=6&max=30&hid=2535&  fTs=me&dRg=7&tab=beats&scO=Recency&");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($doc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further clarification, it seems you're having trouble getting the string value of the individual `<content>` nodes? If so, consider the following:

```
$str = '
<xml>
  <content>content1</content>
  <somethingElse>DOH!</somethingElse>
  <content>content2</content>
  <content>content3</content>
</xml>
';

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$vals = array();
foreach ($doc->content as $content) {
  $vals[] = (string) $content;
}

print_r($vals);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => content1
    [1] => content2
    [2] => content3
)
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, you could use the same tactic above with an additional `implode` call like so:

```
$vals = implode('', $vals);
echo $vals; // outputs: content1content2content3
```

Or, modify the original loop to do:

```
$vals = '';
foreach ($doc->content as $content) {
  $vals .= (string) $content;
}
echo $vals; // outputs: content1content2content3
```

Comment: I'm trying to combine all the content nodes into one string. Sorry if this wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help the print_r just seems to print out "Array ( )" onto the page, any idea why this is? This is from the first block of code without trying to implode the content nodes together.

Comment: @BenPaton Yeah, I only included `print_r` so you could see the contents of the resulting array. That's what `print_r` is supposed to do. You can safely remove it.

Comment: It's not find the content nodes for some reason so $vals is empty. Would the content nodes be another level down e.g. $doc->entry->0->content ?

Comment: Final working code:`$ch = curl_init("http://api.sysomos.com/hb/v1/heartbeat/rss?startid=0&hbrss=DUpnCTqppKjx4q1U6FXd5SWOPFUa2ltLm1haXJAYi1hbmQtcS5jby51aw..&maxC=6&max=30&hid=2535&fTs=me&dRg=7&tab=beats&scO=Recency&");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$vals = array();
foreach ($doc->entry as $entry) {
 $vals[] = (string) $entry->content;
}

$vals = implode(' ', $vals);
echo $vals;`